# Pandas groupby, how to do multiple aggregations on multiple columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    Product    occasion    count
1    cake       wedding     2
2    chairs     funeral     3
3    chairs     wedding     2
```

I want to sum the `count` column and join the `occasion` column by | while grouping the dataframe by product to get one like the below:

```
    Product    occasion          count
1   cake       wedding           2
2   chairs     wedding|funeral   5
```

Right now I am using two groupbys and joining the resulting dataframes. Is there a way to do so in one go? I tried multiple aggregations but couldn't get it right on two columns. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
df2=df.groupby('Product',as_index = False).agg({'occasion':'|'.join,'count':'sum'})
print(df2)
#  Product         occasion  count
#0    cake          wedding      2
#1  chairs  funeral|wedding      5
```

Answer (score 0):

A Groupby-apply and groupby-sum should do the trick:

**Data**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['cake', 'wedding', 2],
             ['chairs', 'wedding', 2],
             ['chairs', 'funeral', 3]], columns = ['Product', 'occasion', 'count'])
```

**Solution**

```
df2 = df.groupby('Product')['occasion'].apply(lambda x: "|".join(x)).reset_index().set_index('Product')
df2['count'] = df.groupby('Product')['count'].sum()
```

**Output**

```
print(df2.to_string())

                occasion  count
Product                        
cake             wedding      2
chairs   wedding|funeral      5
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more simple and powerfull way.

In my case i used sum() as function, but you can use mean() or some other that you need.

```
dfgrouped = df.groupby(['Col1', 'Col2']).sum()
```